# Why is $A'=\phi $ for $A=\{1,i,1+i\}$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Note that set $A=\{1,i,1+i\}$ is bounded. Then why is the derived set $A'$ the empty set?

Comment: what is $A'$????

Comment: A'={z∈C:(B(x;r)＼{z})∩A≠ø}

Comment: By $A'$, do you mean derived set of $A$?

Comment: Yes derived set of A !!!!

Comment: Any discrete set has empty derived set. This is because for every point of $A$ there is a small radius inside which there is nothing but that point (it is called an isolated point, i.e. it is alone, like in a desert island).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A'=\{z\in \mathbb C: B(z,r)\cap (A-\{z\})\neq \phi\}$

Now, you can consider points of $A$ in $\mathbb R^2$ as $1=(1,0); i=(0,1); 1+i=(1,1)$

Now take $r=\frac 14$; then $B(z,r)\cap (A-\{z\})=\phi, \forall z\in A,$ thus any point of $A$ is not a limit point.

Similarly you can show any point not in $A$ will not be a limit point.

Thus derived set will be empty only.